# window.onbeforeunload event not fired if we do not click on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
window.onbeforeunload event is not working for the first time, when we 
reload the url no alert coming while closing the browser tab.
```

But it works when we touch any element on the page and close the tab.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
    var message = 'Important: Please click on \'Save\' button to leave this page.';
    if (typeof event == 'undefined') {
        event = window.event;
    }
    if (event) {
        event.returnValue = message;
    }
    return message;
};


    $(function () {
    $("a").click(function () {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
    });

        });

  });
```

[Sample Code here : https://jsfiddle.net/oe9L0fdb/](https://jsfiddle.net/oe9L0fdb/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior on certain browsers. As described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload):

`To combat unwanted pop-ups, some browsers don't display prompts created in beforeunload event handlers unless the page has been interacted with. Moreover, some don't display them at all.`

Essentially this is to prevent abuse by web pages.